# How can I use fetched const value in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

```
const fetchStocks = () => {
    const API_KEY = "dddd";
    const StockSymbol = 'IBM';
    const API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=${StockSymbol}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
    const StockSymbols = [];
    const StockName = [];
    const StockIndustry = [];



    fetch(API_Call)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                StockSymbols.push(data['Symbol']);
                StockName.push(data['Name']);
                StockIndustry.push(data['Industry']);

                console.log(StockName)
                console.log(StockSymbols)
                console.log(StockIndustry)
            })

    // const table = {
    //     columns: [
    //         { headername: "Symbol", field: "symbol" },
    //         { headername: "Name", field: "name" },
    //         { headername: "Industry", field: "industry" }
    //     ],

    //     rowData: [
    //         { symbol: StockSymbols, name: StockName, industry: StockIndustry }
    //     ]
    // }

    return (
        <div>
            {StockSymbols}, {StockName}, {StockIndustry}
        </div>
    )
};
```

export default fetchStocks;

I'm trying to get stock name, symbol, and industry using Alpha Vantage.

And when I console.log them, it seems like it's working.
[image: Console.log]

But when I try to use them in the return part with {StockSymbols}, {StockName}, {StockIndustry},

nothing passes and nothing shows up.

What do I have to do to use them?

Comment: Can you share a full [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YdFR.png) code example so we can see where this return is and where you are seeing anything not defined? Nothing passes and nothing shows up where?

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: I just wanna check if it's working properly.

Comment: return (
        <div>
            {StockSymbols}, {StockName}, {StockIndustry}
        </div>
    )

Comment: So i just called them directly to the page.

Comment: @lilput se my response below, pushing to a `const` does not re-render the component so you need to use some state.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you are looking for, as your question is not self explanatory enough.

1. Create a component state

```
const [data, setData] = useState({StockName: null, StockSymbols: null, StockIndustry: null})
```

2. Move `fetch(API_Call)` in useEffect hook. (componentDidMount incase not using hooks)

```
useEffect(() => {

fetch(API_Call)
    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }
    )
    .then(
        function (data) {
            setData({
               StockName: data['Symbol'],
               StockSymbols: data['Name'],
               StockIndustry: data['Industry']
            })
        })
}, [])
```

3. Use component state in JSX

```
return (<>
        <p>{data.StockName}</p>
        <p>{data.StockSymbols}</p>
        <p>{data.StockIndustry}</p>
       </>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming to:

- fetch the data on mount of the React component
- then show it in the UI

you'd need to keep some state that re-renders the component. So for you that probably means initiating the array as `const [StockIndustry, setStockIndustry] = useState([]);` and `setStockIndustry([...StockIndustry, data['Symbol']];` in your life cycle method/hook. Simply pushing to the array will not re-render the component.

Comment: I need to use useState for that

Comment: If you're using functional components and just want it to compile that's a good first step imo.

Comment: I'm trying to create a table and use those elements in the table

Comment: Sorry, can you help me with one more thing?

Comment: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'API_Call'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Idk what is going on with this

Comment: So `useEffect` is a life cycle hook that re-runs every time any of its dependencies are updated. `API_Call ` is just a `const` right, so it'll never change. Hence it's safe to just add it to the dependency array.

Comment: `API_Call` is redeclared each render cycle, so if defined external to the effect it's a dependency. You can avoid this by moving it outside the component entirely, or inside the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. So, it is safe to move API_call inside the useEffect..

Comment: @lilput Yes, if nothing else needs to reference it it is safe to move into the effect callback.